# Retrieving Query from Parse.com on Xamarin.Android with many relations

Tags: c#, parse-platform, xamarin, relation

Im trying to figure out how to do this. On the [documentation](https://parse.com/docs/dotnet/guide#relations) it has an example on how to get a query with one relation:

```
// suppose we have a book object
var book = ...

// create a relation based on the authors key
var relation = book.GetRelation<ParseObject>("authors");

// generate a query based on that relation
var query = relation.Query;

// now execute the query
query.FindAsync ();
```

But if i have 3 relations like in my case?
[image]

```
reviewObject =  new ParseObject("Review");
var relationBusiness = reviewObject.GetRelation<ParseObject>("business");
relationBusiness.Add(application.currentBusiness);
var relationUser = reviewObject.GetRelation<ParseObject>("user");
relationUser.Add(ParseUser.CurrentUser);
var relationStaff = reviewObject.GetRelation<ParseObject> ("staff");
relationStaff.Add (application.currentStaff);
```

Please assist.Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It wasn't that hard after all:

```
var query = ParseObject.GetQuery ("Review")
    .WhereEqualTo ("business", relationBusiness)
    .WhereEqualTo ("user", relationUser)
    .WhereEqualTo ("staff", relationStaff);

IEnumerable<ParseObject> reviews = await query.FindAsync();
```

(relationBusiness, relationUser and relationStaff are ParseObject not relations)